# SSL error when trying to PULL from GIT

Tags: git, github

I get this error when I try to pull from my git repository. It was working fine for me suddenly for past 2 days I have this issue.

error: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to bitbucket.org:443  while accessing https://er@bitbucket.org/ei/k.git/info/refs?service=git-
upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed

Comment: Maybe you want to take that up with Bitbucket?  It's not likely something you could fix on your end.

Comment: but it was working properly till some days back. For e.g when I pull from my home it works!!

Comment: Bitbucket and Stash require SSLv3. Not all clients support the negotiation properly.

Comment: what do I do then to make it negotiate properly.

Comment: by the way in my eclipse.ini I added this code 
    -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
and now I can pull from my repository but when I run from the cmd prompt git pull I still get that error. How can I get rid of this error from the cmd prompt too

Comment: http://www.f15ijp.com/2012/08/git-ssl-certificate-problem-how-to-turn-off-ssl-validation-for-a-repo/  one of the best solution which I found

Answer (score 4):

First, BitBucket had (see [its status](http://status.bitbucket.org/)):

> a brief issue with one of our SSH servers.

But I see also that error message when the proxy at work hasn't properly authenticate me:

- I open a browser,
- access http://www.bitbucket.org/ in the browser
- go back to my shell and retry the `git pull`.

*Then*, it works.

since I don't have a proxy at home, I never see that issue there.

[Hariharan Kanakaraja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8174732/hariharan-kanakaraja) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330837/ssl-error-when-trying-to-pull-from-git/19336629#comment124270529_19336629):

> if it is a server terminal, then try to load the `bitbucket.org` from the terminal (`wget https://bitbucket.org/`)

Comment: I tried your instructions but did not help.what I did was opened a broser logged into my account and then from cmd promt ran this pull git.but I still get that SSL error

Comment: if it is a server terminal, then try to load the bitbucket.org from the terminal (wget https://bitbucket.org)

Comment: @HariharanKanakaraja Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.